# Question about algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design, finite-field

https://www.shoup.net/ntb/ntb-v2.pdf, page 523, algortithm IPT

I don't get the for loop, since "k" isn't used anywhere inside the loop. What am i missing?

Comment: Just iterate $\lfloor \ell/2 \rfloor$-times?

Comment: Yes, but what changes from one iteration to another?

Comment: Do you anything about coding?

Comment: We prefer reproducing content on this website over simply leaving links. That way a question or answer isn't made useless to other users after the link goes dead.

Answer (score 1):

Just above the algorithm, the document says:

> If $f$ is irreducible, then $\gcd(X^{q^k}−X, f) = 1$ for all positive
>   integers $k$ up to $\ell /2$

What the loop does is just testing all the $\gcd(X^{q^k}-X,f)$ up to $\ell/2$.

To avoid computing $X^{q^k}$ at each $k$, you just compute $X^{q^k}=(X^{q^{k-1}})^q=h^q$.

At the $k$-th round you will have $h=X^{q^k}$.